# Error: expected a type

Tags: c++

I am trying to use an open source class whose .h file starts with:

```
template <class DT>
class FFTReal
{
public:
enum {          MAX_BIT_DEPTH   = 30    };
typedef DT  DataType;
explicit            FFTReal (long length);
...
```

my first creating a pointer to the class in my private section of my class:

```
ffft::FFTReal<double> *m_fft_object;
```

And then, within an initialization function, create it with

```
m_fft_object = new fft_object((long)(FFTWindowSize));
```

It is in this last line that I get the error "Error:expected a type".
I have done some searches for the error but nothing seems to match my particular problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably this is because `fft_object` is not a type.  You probably meant this:

```
m_fft_object = new ffft::FFTReal<double>(static_cast<long>(FFTWindowSize));
```

I also corrected the C-style cast for you.

As noted in the comments, you should avoid using raw pointers to store object data unless you have a very good reason.  Consider using a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr<ffft::FFTReal<double>>`) if the data should be nullable, otherwise you can simply store an object instance as a value (`ffft::FFTReal<double>`).  Either option will make memory leaks extremely unlikely, whereas when using `new` and raw pointers you have to be extremely careful to delete the allocated object when you are done with it.

Comment: I doubt people *ever* mean to use `operator new`, other than to initialize smart pointers.

Comment: @EduardoLeón Agreed, a smart pointer would be better.  Or, if the variable never needs to be in a not-set state, using a value (`ffft::FFTReal<double>`) instead of a pointer (`ffft::FFTReal<double>*`) would be even better.

Comment: Than you @cdhowie for the solution. It solved my problem. Regarding your comment on avoiding the use of a raw pointer to an object. In my implementation I am creating a wrapper function to a library class and this is the only way I thought I could do it, i.e. creating a pointer to the library class in my private section and adding some functions that initialize (in this case allocate) and use the function. Could you propose a better way to organize such code? thanks

Comment: @user1832746 Without seeing your example code, no.  But if you use a raw instance of the object (without the `*`) then you can use the `&` operator to take a pointer to it.